# how to create a single image flip effect t in a group of images?

Tags: javascript, html, image, css

I have 4 sections - each with a single image and some text.

```
<div class=container>
 <div class=row>
  <div class="1"> img 1 </div>
  <div class="1"> img 2 </div>
 </div>
 <div class=row>
  <div class="1"> img 3 </div>
  <div class="1"> img 4 </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to have the image flip effect - and there are a lot out there.

when I hover or touch (mobile) - I would like the image to flip and show some text.

what I am trying to do is allow the system to only allow one image remain flipped with some text.

I would like to start (when page is loaded) only image 1 is flipped with text - and the other 4 are images. when some one hovers/touch the other images, img 1 reset - and the other one shows the text.

any module that can help me ? I am already using jquery latest and pure/skeleton like for responsive images.

edit1:

by flip effect - I mean

http://codepen.io/ilanf/pen/gjoKl

thanks

Comment: "flip effect" is too ambiguous. It can mean many things and, from the code you provide, we can't assume anything at all. What effect do you refer to? What have you tried? What's not working?

Comment: update question & an example of flip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all "Nice work!". I like your effect.

To answer your question:

1. To have one of your images flipped when the page loads, you have to separate it from the rest and use the `backface` as the default state. By "separate", I mean, use a different class name, id or name.
2. Now, according to the codepen fiddle you gave us, it is impossible for more than images to be flipped simultaneously since the image flips back to its default state when the `mouseout` event is triggered.
3. To flip the image that has the text being visible on default when another image is hovered, use this jQuery script:

---

```
/* Let's suppose you give the image you want originally flipped an
extra class = "default-flipped" */

$(".1").on("mouseover", function() {
    if ($(this).siblings().hasClass("default-flipped")) {
        $("default-flipped").css("transform", rotateY(180deg);
    }
});
```

---

### **EDIT**:

As I promised, here is a working version of what you asked for; or basically what I understood you asked for.

Since you already have found that working fiddle which like and want to replicate, I think trying to reinvent the wheel would be utterly pointless.

→ There are a few things you have to add, though, to the CSS though and of course some jQuery:

### CSS:

```
/* We create a pre-flipped class for the element you want already flipped 
when the page loads. */
.pre-flipped {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    /* That's what the card are supposed to do on hover
    Our already flipped card must already have this rule
    in order to be flipped from the start. */
}

/* If you want the images to be inline change the display
from block to inline-block as shown: */
.flip-images .card-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

In the CSS of your fiddle there is a block of code as shown below which is used to flip the cards on hover:

```
.flip-images .card-wrapper:hover .card {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
} /* I removed it and as it makes things complicated
  when trying to create the hover effect from jQuery. */
```

That's it from the CSS standpoint.

### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // mouseover event
    $(".card-wrapper").on("mouseover", function() {
        // Always leaves one open
        $(this).children().css("transform", "rotateY(180deg)");
        $(this).siblings().children().css("transform", "rotateY(0deg)");
    });
});
```

Check this [codepen](http://codepen.io/angelpolitis/pen/qNdJbp) to see how it works! 😊

Comment: sorry - that is not my effect. I just googled and got that effect - which I liked to replicate. I am looking for the same effect - but any new JS will work.

Comment: So, what's the code you have? Does it do any of this shown or you are starting from scratch?

Comment: I am starting from scratch. I am looking for any pointer to existing jquery modules or codepens that have adapted such code.

Comment: Since you found the code on Google and you also liked it, why don't you build on that to create the final effect you want to achieve?

Comment: good point - I guess if I knew how to do that - I wouldn't be on stack. since I don't - asking here for help/direction.

Comment: Well, generally, only specific are to be asked, but since I have some free time, do you want me to create one for you based on this fiddle? I am going to post it as an answer when I finish.

Comment: Check out my edit @hypermails. I hope it's what you want.